# Select two sums with single get_var statement

Tags: database, query, wpdb

I am trying the following

```
global $wpdb;
$sum = $wpdb->get_var("select sum(first), sum(second) from table where id > 1");
```

I am unable to get the values from each request. I have tried

```
echo $test->sum(first);
```

I have tried to change the sql statement to include AS

```
 $sum = $wpdb->get_var("select sum(first) as firstRequest, sum(second) as secondRequestfrom table where id > 1");

echo $test['firstRequest'];
```

I have tried a `foreach` statement

```
foreach($test as $tester){
  echo $tester['sum(first')];
}
```

and

```
foreach($test as $tester){
  echo $tester['firstRequest'];
}
```

How can I retrieve the sum of multiple rows from a single `get_var` statement? If not possible, and I need the sum of 5 different rows, would I have to create 5 separate `get_var` statements? Would this decrease the querying speed, if so, is it even noticeable?

Comment: why not `get_results` instead?

Comment: @milo - from my understanding of wordpress, since I am looking to return a value, I should use the get_var. I think I tried get_results as well, then tried to iterate though with a foreach statement with no luck.

Comment: get_results along with an AS in the sql statement and a foreach statement combined worked to accomplish what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: add your code as an answer and accept it so it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$wpdb->get_var`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable) will do exactly what the name suggests-- return a single value. So this:

```
$sum = $wpdb->get_var("select sum(first), sum(second) from sums_test where id > 1");
var_dump($sum);
```

Will return the result of `sum(first)`. The rest of the result is lost (though cached I believe).

The method you want is [`get_row`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row) which will return a complete row of results.

```
$sum = $wpdb->get_row("select sum(first) as first_sum, sum(second) as second_sum from sums_test where id > 1");
var_dump($sum);
```

I have added `AS` clauses as well to make it easier to use the data in PHP. You can now get your results with `$sum->first_sum)`, `$sum->second_sum`, and so on for as many as you retrieve, or you may use something something more dynamic like:

```
foreach ($sum as $k=>$v) {
  echo $k.' -> '.$v.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I ended up using get_results instead of get_row along with an AS clause. It seems to produce the same result. Thank you for the dynamic foreach statement! I hadn't thought of a way to write it as good. Thanks again!